# Base64 decoding of a String batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, base64, decode, encode

I want to decode a base64 encoded text and use it to login to a website. The base64 encoded text is the username and password. I hav found tools like Base64.exe and b64.exe but they take input as a file whereas in my case input is a string. plz help me out. All this shud be done in a batch file only and also am reading the encoded text from a config.txt file.

Comment: If you show us what you have tried we might be able to help. If you just need a solution have a look at google first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I am extracting the base64 encoded text from "config.txt" to a new file say "tmp.txt". now I run the cmd "b64.exe -d tmp.txt tmp2.txt".I get the decoded text in the new "tmp2.txt" file. I delete the "tmp.txt" and "tmp2.txt" once i read the username and password. 
Thank you

Comment: what is b64.exe? Doesn't feel windows-native.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `CERTUTIL` command without installing external software (though it will need temp files):

```
@echo off
del /q /f "%temp%\b64"  >nul 2>nul
del /q /f "%temp%\decoded"  >nul 2>nul

set "base64string=YmFzZTY0c3RyaW5n"
echo -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----->"%temp%\b64"
<nul set /p=%base64string% >>"%temp%\b64"
echo -----END CERTIFICATE----->>"%temp%\b64"

certutil /decode "%temp%\b64" "%temp%\decoded" >nul 2>nul


for /f "useback tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%temp%\decoded")  do set "decoded=%%#"
echo %decoded%
del /q /f "%temp%\b64"  >nul 2>nul
del /q /f "%temp%\decoded"  >nul 2>nul
```

You can also use powershell which will be slower despite there will be no temp files:

```
set "base64string=YmFzZTY0c3RyaW5n"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('powershell [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("""%base64string%"""^)^)') do set "decoded=%%#"
echo %decoded%
```

You can try also with  [***atob.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/atob.bat) :

```
call atob.bat YmFzZTY0c3RyaW5n decoded
echo %decoded%
```

Or with [***base64.bat***](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/base64.bat)

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('base64.bat -decode YmFzZTY0c3RyaW5n') do set "decoded=%%#"
echo %decoded%
```

Comment: Good answer, but powershell makes me laugh.  It always seems 5 times more complicated and harder to remember than the comparable linux command.  `echo "string" | base64`

Comment: In case anyone else wonders, `certutil` should be installed on all versions on Windows, starting with Vista / Server 2008. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09fb7a70-69c2-4cc0-ad82-173c06774261/availbility-of-certutil-on-different-windows-versions?forum=winserversecurity

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [macro style](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1827) invented by **@jeb**, **@dbenham** and **@Ed Dyreen**:

```
@echo off
====SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions


set ^"LF=^
%===EXPANDS TO NOTHING===%
"
REM \n is an escaped LF + caret
set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"


REM Initalize macro
set ^"$b64d=FOR %%$ in (%%$ MainMacro) do if "%%$" == "MainMacro" (%\n%
    ^>nul %__APPDIR__%CERTUTIL.EXE -f -decodehex args.tmp proc.tmp 1%\n%
    type proc.tmp%\n%
    del args.tmp proc.tmp%\n%
) ELSE ^>args.tmp echo("


echo BEFORE :: %time%
%$b64d%dGhpcwppcwpzaWNrIQo=
echo AFTER  :: %time%
```

---

Output:

> ```
> BEFORE :: 21:13:31.94
> this
> is
> sick!
> AFTER  :: 21:13:32.02
> ```